# Reports from PMD, checkstyle, findbugs

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have a few modules(projects and subprojects) in my application (in Gradle) and i have added plugins: PMD, checkstyle, findbugs. Those plugins create their own reports in their directory (for example: PMD makes directory "PMD" in directory "reports" and  put there report). I would like to have a one report for all those plugins. It is possible to do that? And if yes, how do that?

Comment: As per my knowledge, NO... (M also interested, if something is available for this.... )

Comment: No, I didn't. I had reports from each in other files.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want take a look at [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). It basically gathers reports of mentioned tools and shows them via nice web app. It can also gather test coverage reports and is free.

Not sure how it can be integrated with Gradle, but we have it integrated with Jenkins. There is also Eclipse plugin I used.

QualityGate (that was mentioned by Csuki) is paid solution.

Comment: gradle integration is possible - I know projects using gradle, bamboo and sonarqube together.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply configure them to create a shared report together. However, you can use  for this purpose either [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) or [QualityGate](https://www.quality-gate.com/). Both tools can execute the above mentioned plugins and they can generate a summarized report as you required.

Comment: How they can be configured to create shared report?

Comment: No configuration needed, simply install them. You can check an online demo of QualityGate here: https://opensource.quality-gate.com/ Click on the "Generate PDF report" button to see it for yourself.

Comment: Do there is needed QualityGate for gathering all the reports? I thought you know some way to doing that without it.

Comment: Yes, you need it. Unfortunately, I don't know any other method to do the summarization without it.